# WooCommerce Subscriptions Extension - Cancel on gateway before cancelling in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the WooCommerce admin, there is the cancel subscription option.
I am able to hook into this to trap when a subscription has been cancelled.
However, I would prefer if I check the gateway and cancel the subscription on the gateway before it is cancelled in WooCommerce.

It needs to be

1. User/Admin selects "Cancel Subscription"
2. API request goes to the gateway to give a success/fail response.
3. On success, WooCommerce cancels the subscription.

In the current setup where it hooks in *after* the subscription is cancelled there is the possibility of the API call failing. The subscription appearing cancelled to the user while at the gateway it may continue to process the payment.

I found the post status hook change will trigger before the subscription has changed, but I am unable to stop further processing on failure without a die().

Does anyone know the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to rearrange the order of how things are done, you should write a function that comes AFTER the gateway call and if it failed, then it should reactivate the subscription and then tell the user to try again. And of course it should be logged and sends you a notification as well.

The reason I suggest this method is that it's much less likely to get broken on a WooCommerce update.

Comment: Good suggestion. 
Is there any issue re-activating a subscription though? As in, does it trigger any other events after the re-activation?
Would it be a simple `WC_Subscriptions_Manager::activate_subscriptions_for_order()`
or a 
`$order->update_status( 'completed' );` ?

Comment: No, I don't think so, but of course testing is always required. The activation function should take care of all the dependencies. Be sure to do a try/catch on that reactivation too.

Please upvote me if you like my answer. I'm trying to get my reputation points up. :)